# How can I efficiently change all black rectangles in a redacted and flattened PDF to white?

Tags: opencv, pdf, computer-vision

I would prefer that redactions appear as erased text and not as black rectangles.

The documents are already flattened, so there is no way to manipulate the redactions directly.

The only solution I have found is Photoshop, but doing this manually is prohibitively time-consuming.

How can I efficiently change all black rectangles in a PDF file to white?

Edit: [examples](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gWmQUMcfsBLzaOYl_vjgCKrvX8nvC9a4?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please share some input images.

Comment: You'll probably need to use Google Drive or Dropbox or similar in order to share PDFs.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gWmQUMcfsBLzaOYl_vjgCKrvX8nvC9a4?usp=sharing

Comment: use a library that lets you manipulate the *data* inside of a PDF. PDF files are vector data. those black rectangles may literally be rectangle objects you can delete, or change. DO NOT work on raster data if you don't have to.

Comment: Which tool are you using to do the redaction? Is it really redacting, or is it just placing a black bar over the text you want redacted? In the second case, stop, and chose a tool which does the first, otherwise, you will experience surprises…

Comment: Christoph, Max - as you can see in the OP's example files, the PDFs contains bitmap images of redacted scans. Thus, most likely the best approach would be to extract those bitmaps, change those bitmaps, and replace the original bitmaps with the manipulated ones, just like @KJ indicated.

Comment: Max, I did not redact the documents. I received them already-redacted. KJ, thank you for the guidance. I was hoping that wouldn't be the case, but it seems it is.